# ccnet not deleting buildlogs

Tags: ccnet-config

I Have the following in my ccnet.config file

```
....
<publishers>
  <xmllogger />
</publishers>
<tasks>
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="5" />
....
```

However the build logs never get removed? Am I misunderstanding this? I would expect never seening more then 5 log files in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Artifact_Cleanup_Publisher) you must put the artifact cleanup publisher in the publishers section for it to work:

```
<publishers>
  <xmllogger />
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="5" />
</publishers>
```